# android expandable List (drop left)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandable

I would like to build a list like image.

1.

2.

3.

4.

when click on item "1" i would like appear like this (two lists).

**1** 1.1

2 1.2

3

4

when click on item "2" i would like appear like this (two lists).

1 2.1

**2** 2.2

3 2.3

4

when click on item "3" i would like appear like this (two lists).

1 3.1

2 3.2

**3** 3.3

4

and so.

I need help, someone has a suggestion.

Comment: can't understand...explain more...When item 1 is clicked 2 1.2 appear...When item 2 clicked 3 2.3 appear...then why not 4 3.4 appear on item 3 click...???

Answer (score 1):

check the following link, it may help u...

http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html

Comment: It's not quite what I want (expandable list).
I want two different and independent lists, side by side.

Comment: ok, but would have to build the tree recursively and dynamic with various levels

Answer (score 0):

you can create two Listview and put them side by side. 1st list will contains 1,2,3,4...n and when you click on any number for e.g. you clicked on 2 then 2.1,2.2,2.3....2.n will appear on 2nd list.

This might help you to understand how ListView is working in Android
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: It's not quite what I want (expandable list). I want two different and independent lists, side by side. I would have to build the tree recursively and dynamic with various levels.

Comment: Second list is a submenu of first list. I hope you noticed

Comment: yes I can notice it, so what is the issue you are facing when you create two ListViews and put them side by side?

Comment: recursively when i clicked in the second list must appear a third and so on

Comment: If you know how to add/remove ListView at run time then you can achieve this

Comment: I'm new in android and this is my problem (add/remove ListView at run time)